# ActivityGroup and SearchDialog

Tags: android

So I have a default searchable Activity in my app, and if I press the search button in simples activities it works. But when I'm in a tab where the content is an ActivityGroup, and not an Activity, the app crashes.

```
08-19 17:18:23.438: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9078): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
08-19 17:18:23.458: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9078): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no ident
08-19 17:18:23.458: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9078):     at android.app.Activity.ensureSearchManager(Activity.java:3499)
08-19 17:18:23.458: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9078):     at android.app.Activity.startSearch(Activity.java:2648)
08-19 17:18:23.458: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9078):     at android.app.Activity.onSearchRequested(Activity.java:2612)
...
```

Even if I add this code in my activityGroup, I'm still crashing :

```
@Override
  public boolean onSearchRequested() {return false;}
```

Comment: I use the in-app QuickSearch in my app that has a TabHost and ActivityGroups, works without a problem. Since the question is of August, I assume the problem has already been resolved? Otherwise please post the search-relevant code from your manifest and/or searchable.xml. Are you overriding the onSearchRequested in the outer activity or the embedded one?

Comment: I am really interested in the solution to this... what could be the problem here? in the first tab the search works - in the second I get the error from above :(

Comment: Can you tell me which activity did you define as searchable? The one extends ActivityGroup(for the tab) or individual activity in that group? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok sorry that I didn't answer sooner.

So yes, the problem is resolved, and I think that it came from the ActivityGroup, where the onSearchRequested() wasn't overrided, but took the event anyway.

So the solution was this :

```
@Override
public boolean onSearchRequested() {
    return mLocalActivityManager.getCurrentActivity().onSearchRequested();
}
```

The mLocalActivityManager is the LocalActivityManager that starts the different activities...

Then you have to override the onSearchRequested() in each Activity that is displayaed in the group, and eventually just return false there, if you don't want the search dialog.

Answer (score 4):

Hi I found that your solution did not work. But it got me thinking. This only happened when a `TabHost` was inside a TabHost. So I put a debugger in the inner most `TabHost` and noticed that `onSearchRequest` never got called. But the Activities inside the inner `TabHost` did. So I added this to the inner Activities

```
@Override
    public boolean onSearchRequested() {
        if (getParent() instanceof TabActivity) {
            return getParent().onSearchRequested();
        } else {
            return super.onSearchRequested();
        }
    }
```

And it works now.

Comment: You should better check for ActivityGroup than for TabActivity as TabActivity is a subclass of ActivityGroup.